# Blueprism Replace Characters in a collection

Tags: blueprism

I have a collection with multiple columns. I want to search for any characters that have a fada/accent (eg. á) and replace them with the normal version of the character. So á would become a. This would be similar to ctrl f replace in excel.

Comment: Calculation stages have a "Replace" function available from the list under Functions:Text>Replace.  To my knowledge, there is no standard feature available to do this once text is inside the collection. However, with this "Replace" function you should be able to have the fada/accents removed before the text goes into the Collection stage.

Answer (score 1):

Calculation stages have a "Replace" function available from the list under Functions>Text.  To my knowledge, there is no standard feature available to do this once text is inside the collection. However, with this "Replace" function you should be able to have the fada/accents removed before the text goes into the Collection stage.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I read a csv sheet into the collection. I don't think a calculation will work for me?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I created an excel macro. The bot runs this macro and then reads the file into a collection